# How can i implement the first name of the contact disappear as i scroll the contacts

Tags: android

In android contacts application, if I set the 'Sort list by' options to 'Last name', when I scroll the contacts list view, the first name of that contact is invisible. But the scrolling stop, the first name of the contact is visible.

I have a list view in my application, how can i get notified when does my list view stops scrolling?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Android API Demos app on the emulator; there's a "slow adapter" example that does this ([source code](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List13.html)). The key part is in the `onScrollStateChanged` method where it checks the `scrollState` for `OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`, `SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL` and `SCROLL_STATE_FLING` (and related state-check code in the `getView` method).